# How do I efficiently create multi-dimensional javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to store information similar to this:

```
tag_array['design1']['0'][0]['x'] = 100;
tag_array['design1']['0'][0]['y'] = 100;
tag_array['design1']['0'][0]['w'] = 710;
tag_array['design1']['0'][0]['h'] = 332;
```

This would work if it is PHP but it's not working in javascript.

How do I create the same array in proper javascript syntax?

Comment: Refer this Post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: well you would be better off with objects than arrays since you are using strings.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can do that because it will make the parent elements too (it actually throws a warning).  In JavaScript, it will error out because the parent elements don't exist.

Instead of making it like that, try to make it all at once like this:

```
var tag_array = {
    design1: {
        '0': [{
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            w: 710,
            h: 332
        }]
    }
};
```

This should give you the structure you want.

**UPDATE**: Answer has been updated to reflect the fact that the 1st `0` can be a string.

Comment: but it is a string "0" not an integer.

Comment: String versions of numeric properties can be used with numerically-indexed array elements, @epascarello, but you're right it's not clear which setup the OP wants.

Comment: OP here. Yes, the first "0" is a string. Can be replaced with any other strings.

Comment: In javascript, when you access a property it is accessed as a string. Since arrays are just fancy objects, they behave the same way. `a[0]` and `a["0"]` do the same thing because in the first case the number `0` is converted to a string before looking up the property.

Comment: @Rocket How do I directly insert into number 4 using your syntax? Like the following: tag_array['design1']['0'][4]

Comment: @komirad: after running the code I show, yes that should work :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it programatically then because JavaScript requires you to have this type of structure

```
tag_array = {};
tag_array['design1'] = {};
tag_array['design1']['0'] = [];
tag_array['design1']['0'][0] = {};
tag_array['design1']['0'][0]['x'] = 100;
```

you can make a `prototype` function to create the object/array structure for you

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'addDimensions', { value: function(){
    var prop = arguments[0];
    if(this[prop] !== undefined){
        if(typeof this[prop] !== 'object') throw 'Property "'+prop+'" is already defined.'
    }else{
        if(arguments.length > 1 && ~~arguments[1] === arguments[1] && arguments[1] >= 0) this[prop] = [];
        else this[prop] = {};
    }
    if(arguments.length > 1){
        this[arguments[0]].addDimensions.apply(
            this[arguments[0]],
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)
        );
    }
    return this;
},
enumerable: false });
```

and call it on an empty object `{}`

```
var myArrayLikeObject = ({}).addDimensions('design1','0',0); // {design1: [ [ {} ] ] }
```

or an array `[]` (only if first arg is an integer)

```
var myMultiArray = [].addDimensions(0,'hi',0); // [ {hi: [ {} ] } ]
```

or on an existing array or object

```
var a = [0,1,2];
a.addDimensions(3,0); // a = [0, 1, 2, [ {} ] ]
```

Comment: You'll need to modify it a little to check for existing sub-arrays / objects if you want to call it multiple times on the same indices

Comment: -1: a) Never add enumerable properties to `Object.prototype`, b) use objects (`{}`) for non-numeric properties, not arrays

Comment: @Bergi, does the edit I just made solve the issues you had with it?